# Equivalent of validation plot in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to write the code to plot 
`validationplot {pls}`'s equivalent using ggplot.

I could make this using base R, but could'nt figure out how to plot this in ggplot. Can someone please help me?

```
library(pls)
library(ggplot2)
library(ISLR)
data("College")
clg=College

cat("Partitioning 50/50")
set.seed(702)
trainindex=sample(1:nrow(clg),size=ceiling(nrow(clg)/2))

ctrain=clg[trainindex,]
ctest=clg[-trainindex,]

dim(ctrain)
dim(ctest)

pcre = pcr(Apps ~ .,
           data = ctrain,
           scale = T,
           validation = "CV")
#Validation plot
vplote = validationplot(pcre, val.type = "MSEP", xaxt = "none")
axis(1, at = 0:17, labels = 0:17)
abline(
  h = c(1:30) / 3 * 1e6,
  v = c(0:17),
  col = "gray",
  lty = 3
)
```

Comment: Do the PLS / PCR examples in https://bradleyboehmke.github.io/HOML/linear-regression.html help you with what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply find the MSEP using the MSEP function on your pcre variable and from there you can handle everything with ggplot (see the code and image below).

```
library(pls)
library(ggplot2)
library(ISLR)
data("College")
clg=College

cat("Partitioning 50/50")
set.seed(702)
trainindex=sample(1:nrow(clg),size=ceiling(nrow(clg)/2))

ctrain=clg[trainindex,]
ctest=clg[-trainindex,]

dim(ctrain)
dim(ctest)

pcre = pcr(Apps ~ .,
           data = ctrain,
           scale = T,
           validation = "CV")

#Validation ggplot

ggplot(data.frame(Components=0:17,MSEP=MSEP(pcre)$val[1, 1,]),
       aes(x=Components,y=MSEP))+geom_line()+geom_point()
```

[image]